# Why is e(n) not converging for this LMS algorithm. Whats wrong in this implementation of LMS algorithm

Tags: vhdl

We are writing a code to implement LMS algorithm.  We are implementing the following [enter link description here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/lmsfilter.html) equations. But the error is not converging. After large number of iterations , e(n) is becoming equal to y(n).What is the fault in this code?

The desired signal d(n) is sine3(iii)[a sinusoidal signal] and the input signal is sine2(iii), the delayed version of input is sine2(jj).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_Unsigned.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;


entity freq_div is

     generic ( width : integer :=  4 ); 
    Port (clk_p, clk_n : in  STD_LOGIC;

          LED : out  STD_LOGIC:='0';

         seconds : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         minutes : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         hours : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

        random_num : out std_logic_vector (width-1 downto 0); 
        data_outa,data_outb,data_outc,data_outd,output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

           count : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0));
end freq_div;

architecture Behavioral of freq_div is

signal sec,min,hour : integer range 0 to 60 :=0;
signal counta : integer :=1;
signal clka : std_logic :='0';

signal clk2: std_logic;
signal cnt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
signal clk: std_logic_vector(28 downto 0):=(others=>'0');

signal data_out1,rand_temp1,noisy_signal,data_outb1,data_outc1,data_outd1, summation_signal : integer;
signal noisy_signal1,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal summation_signal1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
signal i : integer :=0;
signal j : integer :=120;
signal k : integer :=40;
signal l : integer :=80;
signal ii: integer :=0 ;
signal iii: integer :=2 ;
signal jj: integer :=1 ;
signal kk: integer :=60 ;
signal ll: integer :=90 ;
signal ii_gate: std_logic := '0';
signal a : integer := 0;
signal s : real:= 0.01;
signal v,srs : real;
signal t: integer :=3;
signal yy:real;
signal er1:real;



signal LED1 :STD_LOGIC := '0';

type memory_type is array (0 to 359) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
signal sine2,sine3 : memory_type;
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=(x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"06",
x"06",x"07",x"07",x"08",x"08",x"09",x"09",x"0a",x"0a",x"0b",
x"0b",x"0c",x"0c",x"0d",x"0d",x"0e",x"0e",x"0f",x"0f",x"10",
x"11",x"11",x"12",x"13",x"13",x"14",x"15",x"15",x"16",x"17",
x"18",x"18",x"19",x"1a",x"1b",x"1b",x"1c",x"1d",x"1e",x"1e",
x"1f",x"20",x"21",x"22",x"23",x"23",x"24",x"25",x"26",x"27",
x"28",x"29",x"2a",x"2b",x"2c",x"2d",x"2f",x"2f",x"30",x"31",
x"32",x"34",x"35",x"35",x"36",x"37",x"38",x"39",x"3a",x"3b",
x"3c",x"3c",x"3e",x"3f",x"40",x"41",x"42",x"43",x"44",x"45",
x"46",x"46",x"47",x"48",x"49",x"49",x"4a",x"4b",x"4c",x"4c",
x"4e",x"4f",x"4f",x"50",x"51",x"51",x"52",x"53",x"53",x"54",
x"55",x"55",x"56",x"57",x"57",x"58",x"58",x"59",x"59",x"5a",
x"5a",x"5b",x"5b",x"5c",x"5c",x"5d",x"5d",x"5e",x"5e",x"5f",
x"5f",x"5f",x"60",x"60",x"60",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"62",
x"62",x"62",x"62",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",
x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"64",x"63",x"63",x"63",x"63",
x"63",x"63",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"62",x"61",x"61",x"61",x"60",
x"60",x"60",x"5f",x"5f",x"5f",x"5e",x"5e",x"5d",x"5d",x"5c",
x"5c",x"5b",x"5b",x"5a",x"5a",x"59",x"59",x"58",x"58",x"57",
x"57",x"56",x"55",x"55",x"54",x"54",x"53",x"53",x"52",x"51",
x"51",x"50",x"4f",x"4f",x"4e",x"4d",x"4c",x"4c",x"4b",x"4a",
x"49",x"49",x"48",x"47",x"46",x"46",x"45",x"44",x"44",x"43",
x"42",x"41",x"41",x"40",x"3f",x"3e",x"3d",x"3c",x"3c",x"3b",
x"3a",x"39",x"38",x"37",x"36",x"35",x"35",x"34",x"33",x"32",
x"31",x"30",x"2f",x"2f",x"2e",x"2d",x"2c",x"2b",x"2a",x"29",
x"28",x"28",x"27",x"26",x"25",x"24",x"23",x"23",x"22",x"21",
x"20",x"1f",x"1e",x"1e",x"1d",x"1c",x"1b",x"1b",x"1a",x"19",
x"18",x"18",x"17",x"16",x"15",x"15",x"14",x"13",x"13",x"12",
x"11",x"11",x"10",x"0f",x"0f",x"0e",x"0d",x"0d",x"0c",x"0c",
x"0b",x"0b",x"0a",x"0a",x"09",x"09",x"08",x"08",x"07",x"07",
x"06",x"06",x"05",x"05",x"05",x"04",x"04",x"04",x"03",x"03",
x"03",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"02",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",x"01",
x"01",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00",x"00");


COMPONENT ila_1

PORT (  clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    probe0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT  ;

 begin

 --seconds <= conv_std_logic_vector(sec,6);
 --minutes <= conv_std_logic_vector(min,6);
 --hours <= conv_std_logic_vector(hour,5);

 seconds <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(sec,6));
 minutes <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(min,6));
 hours <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(hour,5));

   IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
  generic map (
     DIFF_TERM => FALSE, -- Differential Termination 
     IBUF_LOW_PWR => TRUE, -- Low power (TRUE) vs. performance (FALSE) setting for referenced I/O standards
     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
  port map (
     O => clk2,  -- Buffer output
     I => clk_p,  -- Diff_p buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
     IB => clk_n -- Diff_n buffer input (connect directly to top-level port)
  );

 process(clk2)
  begin
  if(clk2'event and clk2='1') then
  counta <=counta+1;
  if(counta = 5) then
  clka <= not clka;
  counta <=1;
  end if;
  end if;
  end process;

  process(clka)   --period of clk is 1 second.
  variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0):=(width-1 => '1',others => '0');
  variable temp : std_logic := '0';
  variable y,er : real;
  variable w1,w2 : real :=0.0;
  variable u : real:= 0.00002;

  begin

  if(clka'event and clka='1') then

  LED1 <= not LED1; 
  LED <= LED1;
  temp := rand_temp(width-1) xor rand_temp(width-2);
  rand_temp(width-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(width-2 downto 0);
  rand_temp(0) := temp;

  i <= i+ 1;
  if(i = 359) then
  i <= 0;
  end if;

  j <= j+ 1;
  if(j = 359) then
  j <= 0;
  end if;

  k <= k+ 1;
  if(k = 359) then
  k <= 0;
  end if;

  l <= l+ 1;
  if(l = 359) then
  l <= 0;
  end if;

  data_outa <= sine(i);

  data_outb <= sine(j);
  data_outc <= sine(k);
  data_outd <= sine(l);

  data_out1<=to_integer(unsigned(sine(i)));
  random_num <= rand_temp;
  rand_temp1<=to_integer(unsigned(rand_temp));
  noisy_signal<=data_out1+rand_temp1;
  noisy_signal1<= std_logic_vector(to_signed(noisy_signal,8));

 srs<=real(to_integer(signed(sine(i))));

  sine2(ii)<=noisy_signal1;
  sine3(ii)<=sine(i);
       ii <= ii+ 1;
           if(ii = 359) then
           ii <=0;
           ii_gate <= '1';
           end if;

       if ii_gate = '1' then     
       s1 <= sine2(iii);
       s5 <= sine3(iii);
       output <=s1;
       iii <= iii+ 1;
       if(iii = 359) then
       iii <= 0;
       end if;

      s2 <= sine2(jj);
      jj <= jj+ 1;
      if(jj = 359) then
      jj <= 0;
      end if;
       s3 <= sine2(kk);
       kk <= kk+ 1;
       if(kk = 359) then
       kk <= 0;
       end if;
       s4 <= sine2(ll);
       ll <= ll+ 1;
       if(ll = 359) then
       ll <= 0;
       end if;

        if(a<350) then
            --write your code here..

            y:= real(to_integer(signed(sine2(iii))))*w1+ real(to_integer(signed(sine2(jj))))*w2;--y(n)=w(Transpose)(n-1)*u(n);u(n) is the input signal
            er:=y-real(to_integer(signed(sine3(iii))));--e(n)=d(n)-y(n)
            if(er<0.0)then
            er:=-er;--Taken modulus value of error
            end if;
            w1:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(sine2(iii))))+w1;--w(n)=w(n-1)+u*e(n)*u(complex congugate)(n);since we dont have complex values, we dont need to take conjugate 
            w2:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(sine2(jj))))+w2;


--          y:= real(to_integer(signed(s3)))*w1+ real(to_integer(signed(s4)))*w2;
--          er:=y-real(to_integer(signed(s5)));--sine3(iii);
--          w1:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(s3)))+w1;
--          w2:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(s4)))+w2;

            yy<=y;
            er1<=er;   
              a<=a+1;  --increment the pointer 'j'.

        end if;

       end if;

  sec <= sec+ 1;
  if(sec = 59) then
  sec<=0;
  min <= min + 1;
  if(min = 59) then
  hour <= hour + 1;
  min <= 0;
  if(hour = 23) then
  hour <= 0;
  end if;
  end if;
  end if;
  end if;

  end process;


--    process(clk2, rst)
--        begin
--            if (rst = '1')then
--                clk <= (others=>'0');
--            elsif (clk2'event and clk2 = '1')then
--                clk <= clk + 1;
--            end if;
--    end process;


--  process(clk(25), rst,up,pause) 
--      begin
--      if (rst = '1') then
--          cnt <= (others=>'0');
--      elsif (clk(25) = '1' and clk(25)'event) then
--          if (up = '1' and pause = '0')then
--              cnt <= cnt + '1';
--          elsif (up = '0' and pause = '0') then
--              cnt <= cnt - '1';
--          elsif( pause ='1')then
--              cnt <= cnt;
--          end if;
--      end if;
--  end process;

--  count <= cnt;






end Behavioral;
```

Please concentrate on this part of the code, as the equations have been implemented here:

```
if(a<1000) then
            --write your code here..

            y:= real(to_integer(signed(sine2(iii))))*w1+ real(to_integer(signed(sine2(jj))))*w2;--y(n)=w(Transpose)(n-1)*u(n);u(n) is the input signal
            er:=y-real(to_integer(signed(sine3(iii))));--e(n)=d(n)-y(n)
            if(er<0.0)then
            er:=-er;--Taken modulus value of error
            end if;
            w1:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(sine2(iii))))+w1;--w(n)=w(n-1)+u*e(n)*u(complex congugate)(n);since we dont have complex values, we dont need to take conjugate 
            w2:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(sine2(jj))))+w2;


--          y:= real(to_integer(signed(s3)))*w1+ real(to_integer(signed(s4)))*w2;
--          er:=y-real(to_integer(signed(s5)));--sine3(iii);
--          w1:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(s3)))+w1;
--          w2:=u*er*real(to_integer(signed(s4)))+w2;

            yy<=y;
            er1<=er;   
              a<=a+1;  --increment the pointer 'j'.

        end if;
```

Comment: Where the LMS algorithm is? Your actual code is just doing a lot of useless computation from seconds to degrees, sine,...

Comment: Sir please check on the portion if(a<1000) then end if;the LMS equations have been implemented there

Answer (score 1):

Go back to your original code, in Python, Matlab, Ada, Java or whatever.

Did that converge?

If not, fix that first.

If it did, then focus on each step of the calculation in turn, to see where this implementation diverges from the original. Fix that step and try again.